# HTML/Angular - Opening a Select box programmatically with another button click

Tags: html, angular

Below is my HTML select box

```
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```

We know that select box opens when we click on it, but is it possible to open a select box using click of another button? Lets say, I have a button like below and need to open the select box by clicking on this button

```
    <button (click)="openSelect()">OPEN</button>
```

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. It's not possible directly as there isn't a default method to open it in JavaScript.

You can emulate what you are trying to do by creating something similar to a select with the help of `ul` and `li`. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tkshz/

Another way would be to increase the size of the select manipulating the DOM with [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) when the user clicks the button.

However it's not a clean solution. At the end the best way is use other options such as [Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) as it's easier to do stuff like that.